# JavaScript not working in aspx C# webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My JavaScript is not working, when I put it in asps webpage inside a script tag. Code is in the images and in code as well.

It is actually a model box to open images like `lightBox/fancyBox` but it only open the model box for 1 second, but it works in normal html page

[image: ASP and HTML code]

[image: JavaScript]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="img-model.aspx.cs" >Inherits="webpages_img_model" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>model box</title>
 <style>
       /* The Modal (background) */
       .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
             border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 60%;
            height:auto;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
         .clear {
            clear:both;
         }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                 cursor: pointer;
            }
           .modal-content .p1 {
               float:left;
              border-right:1px;
              width:50%;
            }
           .modal-content .p2 {
               float:right;
               width:50%;

            }
           #img {
          position:relative;
          width:400px;
          height:400px;

      }
     #img #mm{
          position:absolute;
          top:0px;
          right:0px;
          z-index: 16;
      }
      #img img{
          width:100%;
          height:auto;
      }
    </style>


 </head>
 <body>

     <form id="form1" runat="server">

          <h2>Modal Example</h2>
     <div id="img">
         <a href="">
             <img src="../images/1pic.jpg" width="400px" height="400px" />
             <span id="mm"><button id="d">MM</button> </span>
         </a>
     </div>
     <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
     <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

     <!-- The Modal -->
     <div id="myModal" class="modal">

         <!-- Modal content -->
         <div class="modal-content">
             <span class="close">×</span>

                      <div class="p1" >
                          <img src="../images/1pic.jpg" height="100%" width="80%" > />
                     </div>

                      <div class="p2">
                 <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
         <p>Some text ithe Modal..</p> <br />
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
                      </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>

    </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

              // Get the button that opens the modal
              var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

              // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
               var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

              // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
                btn.onclick = function () {
                 modal.style.display = "block";
              }

              // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                 span.onclick = function () {
                  modal.style.display = "none";
              }

              // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            $window.onclick = function (event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                      modal.style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
         </script>



         </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Like Pang says, give us code, not screenshots. Also you have not told us what is not working? Do you have errors? Is it not doing something it's supposed to do? What is it even supposed to do? This is such a bad question right now.

Comment: sorry, i tried but it was giving me errors. i spent 20 minutes on that and than decided to put images

Comment: okay should i put code inside double quotes. to be really honest, i am trying to do it again but can't  figure out how. i press code button and than paste the code and it shows same error again

Comment: If you can't figure out how to format code in a SO question, I fear that perhaps you are not cut out for programming...

Comment: i have done that now thanks btw i'm just a beginner i need this for my assignment . i have networking major but this is web development final year project

Comment: This site gets between 5 and 10 thousand questions asked every single day, if you are not going to expend the effort to make a decent question, then you should expect a little hostility in return. But if you ask a well researched and reasoned question, you will get some amazing support. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: okay  it's my first time posting question on this site. i did not know how to use this sorry about that

Comment: Without running the code but just going by your description, your issue is that when the user clicks on the button it will reload the page, what you need to do is prevent the page from loading again by using javascript. Using `onclick="return false;"` usually helps

Comment: Window.onclick is not defined it says in javascript error. How can you debug js error? if you are using firefox for example, you can press F12 on keyboard and go to console to see if there is any error is firing on JS. you can debug your js from debugging tab. hope this helps

Comment: sorry Alex W, i tried that model box appeared for 1 sec and disappeared again

Comment: IN window.onclick , i accidentally wrote $. when i was trying to write query instead of javascript in same file i know it sounds stupid hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented your issue when the user clicks on the Open Modal button it submits the form which means essentially reloaded the page. What you need to do is return false on your `btn.onclick = function ()` function. For simplicity I have posted all the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="img-model.aspx.cs" >Inherits="webpages_img_model" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>model box</title>
    <style>
        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 60%;
            height:auto;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .modal-content .p1 {
            float:left;
            border-right:1px;
            width:50%;
        }
        .modal-content .p2 {
            float:right;
            width:50%;
        }
        #img {
            position:relative;
            width:400px;
            height:400px;
        }
        #img #mm{
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            z-index: 16;
        }
        #img img{
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <div id="img">
            <!-- added # -->
            <a href="#">
                <!-- I would set the dimensions width and height in CSS -->
                <img src="../images/1pic.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
                <span id="mm">
                    <button id="d">MM</button> </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">×</span>
                <div class="p1" >
                    <img src="../images/1pic.jpg" height="100" width="80" />
                </div>
                <div class="p2">
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
                    <p>Some text ithe Modal..</p> <br />
                    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p> <br />
                    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
            btn.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                /* added to prevent the page to submitting */
                return false;
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            /* got rid of the $window and just replaced it with window */
            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I made some other changes as well to the html and javascript, see inline comments

Comment: thank you sir, you have have solved my problem. i really appreciate your help.   thanks